# Reading from text file into parallel Java arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I've found a lot of similar questions on Stack Overflow so far, but none of them have actually answered my question. How do I read the data from different columns in a text file into three separate arrays?

Currently my BufferedReader is going through the entire text file and reading it line by line. The problem is, each line is stored as a singular array element.

As you can see, I tried to access the array elements by calling certain data from the "lines[]" array, which contains all of the lines in the file as separate elements. I just have no idea how to access those elements individually and then store them all in separate arrays. Below are the contents of the text file I'm reading from, and then the Java code itself.

```
(Name,Team,Score)
John,Blue,20
Jamie,White,28
Jonathan,Blue,19
Ron,White,39
Ron,Blue,29
```

--

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Bowling7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("bowling.txt")));
            System.out.println("File open successful!");

            int line = 0;
            String[] lines;
            String[] names;
            String[] teams;
            int[] scores;

            for (String x = fin.readLine(); x != null; x = fin.readLine()) {
                lines = x.split(",");
                teams[line] = lines[line];
                scores[line] = lines[line];
                line++;
            }

            System.out.println(lines[0]);
            System.out.println(lines[1]);

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File I/O error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't `teams[line] = lines[line]; scores[line] = lines[line];` be `teams[line] = lines[1]; scores[line] = lines[2];`

Comment: What you have should basically work, although I only see teams and scores being assigned, not names.  What error do you see?

Comment: Sazz found the obvious error, if that doen't fix it please let us know what is different from what you expect.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I thought so at first, because that's how I would do the second term, but look at it again, there's a semi-colon after the `x!=null;`  It reads again only after the loop complete.

Comment: @markspace - I thought so at first too, so not good code for easy comprehension (since deleted)

Comment: *"How do I read the data from different columns in a text file into three separate arrays?"* Why would you want to? Java is an [**Object-Oriented**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language. Use it, i.e. create a class with 3 fields, then load the data into a single list/array of those objects.

Comment: @ScaryWombat and somehow I didn't pick up that OP was writing to arrays that he hasn't initialized yet (read Elliot's answer below).  I'm definitely need more caffeine right now.

Comment: *doesn't seem to be working* is not a good error description

Comment: @ScaryWombat -- Precise error description is that each separate *line* of the text file is being stored as a single element in the array. We haven't learned how to create a class with three fields, and we've barely touched lists. The only thing we've actually been taught is how to initialize and populate arrays...so I'm pretty confused at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays have a fixed length, your approach is off because you assume they are dynamic. Use a `Collection`, like `List`, and you can use `Files.readAllLines(Path)` to get all of the lines with one call. Remember to skip the first line (the header), and parse the score. Like,

```
File f = new File("bowling.txt");
try {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath());
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> teams = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String line : lines.subList(1, lines.size())) {
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        names.add(tokens[0]);
        teams.add(tokens[1]);
        scores.add(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]));
    }
    System.out.println("Names: " + names);
    System.out.println("Teams: " + teams);
    System.out.println("Scores: " + scores);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get

```
Names: [John, Jamie, Jonathan, Ron, Ron]
Teams: [Blue, White, Blue, White, Blue]
Scores: [20, 28, 19, 39, 29]
```

Comment: Got an error message that says, "Exception java.io.IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement." I tried changing my main function declaration to: public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {...... NetBeans said, "FileNotFoundException class not found." Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @GY [`File.readAllLines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) throws the `IOException`.  Did you keep the first line of the `try` block?

Comment: Is it File.readAllLines(f.toPath()) or FileS.readAllLines(f.toPath())? When I use "File," singular, Java complains that it can't find the class; when I use "Files," plural, Java says "cannot find symbol" and gives the "IO Exception never thrown" error in compilation.

Comment: Click the link. It's `java.nio.file.Files`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```
 List<String> lines= Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());

    String[] teams=new String[lines.size()],names=new String[lines.size()];
    int[] scores=new int[lines.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        String[] sections=lines.get(i).split(",");
        names[i]=sections[0];
        teams[i]=sections[1];
        scores[i]= Integer.parseInt(sections[2]);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(teams));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scores));
```

Comment: code only answers are frowned upon, please explain **what** you have changed

Comment: Also, usually in my code I would hesitate to use `Lists` and `Arrays` unless there is a very good reason